# The question about the word of "Mathematics".

Tags: combinatorics

I have got a problem that contains three things;

i) How many different words can be formed by a rearrangement the letters of the word "mathematics"?

ii) How many of these words begin and end with t?

iii) How many words contain the character string "math" somewhere in that word?

Could you please tell me what to do?

(By the way, I've translated them into English from Danish. I know it causes misunderstanding.)

Comment: I don't think any words are anagrams of "mathematics." :-) Did you mean how many distinct strings you can form?

Comment: No English word other than "mathematics" is an anagram of "mathematics."

Comment: I am sure that the OP meant "How many different strings can be formed by a rearrangement the letters of the word "mathematics"?". This ensures that the question is about maths rather than English. Anyway, in mathematics, "string" and "word" are basically [synonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 4):

No English word other than *mathematics* is an anagram of *mathematics*.

However, using the letters in the word *mathematics*, we can form the following words:

> asthmatic, mismatch, attaches, thematic, schemata, matches, atheism, atheist, attache, aitches, chemist, satiate, miasma, attach, attics, asthma, tamest, thames, themas, theism, theist, tithes, ethics, itches, chaste, cheats, chimes, sachet, static, stitch, scathe, schema, maths, mates, matte, match, mamas, maims, maces, meats, mites, mitts, mimes, attic, aches, tames, tacit, taste, theta, teams, teats, teach, times, tithe, hates, haste, heats, heist, emits, ethic, imams, items, caste, chats, chasm, chase, cheat, chest, chime, chits, cites, smith, smite, state, steam, shame, math, mate, matt, mats, mama, maim, mace, mast, mash, meat, mesh, mite, mitt, mime, mica, mice, mist, ahem, aims, acme, acts, ache, aces, asia, tame, tact, that, thai, them, this, team, teat, teas, tech, test, time, ties, tits, tics, hams, hate, hats, hems, heat, hits, emit, eats, each, east, etch, imam, item, itch, ices, came, cams, cats, cast, cash, case, chat, chit, cite, cist, same, stem, stet, sham, semi, seam, seat, seth, sect, siam, site, scam, scat, mat, mac, mas, met, ate, aha, aim, act, ace, ash, tat, the, tea, tie, tit, tic, hmm, ham, hat, has, hem, him, hit, hic, his, ems, eat, eta, est, its, ice, cam, cat, sam, sat, sac, she, sea, set, sec, sit, sic, me, ms, am, at, ah, as, ha, he, hi, em, eh, im, it, is, a.

---

If with *words* you meant *strings*, as **user1729** suggested, then, because the word *mathematics* contains $11$ characters, there are $11!$ strings.

However, because the letters *m*, *a* and *t* are repeated once, this changes the count to

$$
\frac{11!}{2!2!2!}=\frac{11!}{8}=4989600.
$$

To find the number of words that start and end with *t*, that is, words which fit the template

```
t _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ t
```

we do as above and compute

$$
\frac{9!}{2!2!}=\frac{9!}{4}=90720.
$$

Finally, the number of strings which contain the sub-string *math* is $8!$ because, as **John Adamski** pointed out, we are only considering the characters in the string *ematics*, which contains $7$ unique characters, plus the string *math* as a whole.

Comment: Here are some multi-word anagrams: http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=mathematics&t=1000&a=n

Comment: I am sure that the OP meant "How many different strings can be formed by a rearrangement the letters of the word "mathematics"?". This ensures that the question is about maths rather than English. Anyway, in mathematics, "string" and "word" are basically [synonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)).

Comment: I think there are actually 8! string which contain the sub-string "math". We count the number of permutation of the 8 objects {e,m,a,t,i,c,s,math}.

Comment: @JohnAdamski, I totally agree. Thank you for pointing that out.